# Kendo color picker in a jQuery popup dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using the jQuery popup dialog box and have placed a Kendo colorpicker inside. The color picker works and is editable however the text input is not selectable or editable. This means I cannot allow users to edit the hex value meaning they can only choose using the color wheel.

Any ideas?

```
@model string

@{
    var currentColor = "FFFFFF";
    if(Model != null){
        currentColor = Model;
    }
}

@(Html.Kendo().ColorPicker()
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
    .Value(currentColor)
    .Buttons(true)
    .HtmlAttributes(new {
        id=ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the fields in the model as editable.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                             model: {
                              id: "ColorId",
                              fields: {
                               field1: { editable: false },
                               field2: { editable: false },
                               Color: { editable: true }, 
                            }
                         }      
                 });
```